# Making a button link to another page that I also created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a website for my own learning. I am trying to have the user click on a button and move from one page to another.

I have been looking online and have tried a couple different recommendations for how to create & link the button.

Currently I am working with three files:

main.js:

```
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Results from './Results.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Res.vue:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { print } from "util";

export default Vue.extend({...});

</script>

<style>
...
</style>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
...
<div class='button'>
      <a href='./Results.vue'>
        <v-btn small color="blue">Click here to get results</v-btn>
      </a>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import { print } from "util";

Vue.use(Vuetify)
... (button stuff is not referenced again)
</script>

<style>
... (not button stuff here)
</style>
```

I am using http://localhost:8080/ and when I click the button it goes to http://localhost:8080/Res.vue but still loads the same page. I suspect I am forgetting a call in App.vue's  or something in main.js

Comment: are you not using vue router ???? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: Vue file doesn't work like .html file, Results.vue is a component, you have to make a new route for results. I suggest using vue router.

Answer (score 3):

Add routes to your project

```
// routes example
[
  { path: '/', component: Main }, // some main component here
  { path: '/results', component: Res } // your Res component
]
```

Do not forget past `<router-view /'>` into `App.vue`

Use `to` property to create a linked button (you don't need outer 'a' tag)

```
<v-btn to='/results' small color="blue">Click here to get results</v-btn>
```

Or `:to='{name: 'results'}'` if you named your routes.

```
<v-btn :to='{name: "results"}' small color="blue">Click here to get results</v-btn>
```

Comment: I may not have asked my question well (based off of this site's use of vue-router https://grokonez.com/frontend/vue-js/vue-router-example-with-nav-bar-dynamic-route-nested-routes) but I was thinking of it loading a new page. Is this the right way to do that?